# Association Rule mining using AND Condition

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, apriori

I have a student data set. I have the fields subject,grade and rating of the course given by student. I want to form association rules based on these fields.How could I do it?Is there a way to use "AND" in the association rule mining.I would be interested in python implementation. I have the data like this:

```
Id|Sem|Grade|Rating|SUB
1|2|A|3|sub1
1|4|C|1|sub2
2|2|B|2|sub1
```

I tried it with usual association code like this:

```
records=[]
for i in range(0,60):
    records.append([str(dfrslt.values[i,j]) for j in range(0,5)])
```

I got some frozen set data as output like this:

```
[RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'0'}), support=0.3333333333333333, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'0'}), confidence=0.3333333333333333, lift=1.0)])
```

I don't understand this output too.
Is there anyway I could get some tabular format of data in an understandable way?

Comment: What's `dfrslt`?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity my data frame

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)? What's your expected output?

Comment: @rpanai for example: if grade for sub1 is A and rating is 1,in the smilar way if the grade for sub2 is A and rating is 1 too, then sub1=>sub2. I want the output with a table of frequent item sets